# webRTC - record audio with RecordRTC and convert to mp3 using lamejs

Tags: javascript, recordrtc

I am trying to record stream audio using recordRTC. But I would like to convert the output into mp3 in real time. For the conversion I came across lamejs. I found a couple of examples. But I don't know how to use them for what I want.

I get a `blob`

```
mediaRecorder = RecordRTC(webcamStream,{type: 'audio', mimeType: 'audio/mpeg-3',});
mediaRecorder.startRecording();

mediaRecorder.stopRecording(function() {
     let blob = mediaRecorder.getBlob();

}
```

lamejs example that I am trying to fix my needs into.

```
channels = 1; //1 for mono or 2 for stereo
sampleRate = 44100; //44.1khz (normal mp3 samplerate)
kbps = 128; //encode 128kbps mp3
mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(channels, sampleRate, kbps);
var mp3Data = [];

samples = new Int16Array(44100); //one second of silence (get your data from the source you have)
sampleBlockSize = 1152; //can be anything but make it a multiple of 576 to make encoders life easier

var mp3Data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < samples.length; i += sampleBlockSize) {
  sampleChunk = samples.subarray(i, i + sampleBlockSize);
  var mp3buf = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(sampleChunk);
  if (mp3buf.length > 0) {
      mp3Data.push(mp3buf);
  }
}
var mp3buf = mp3encoder.flush();   //finish writing mp3

if (mp3buf.length > 0) {
    mp3Data.push(new Int8Array(mp3buf));
}

var blob = new Blob(mp3Data, {type: 'audio/mp3'});
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
console.log('MP3 URl: ', url);
```

How can I pass the recorded buffer to lamejs in realtime?

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer in case anyone needs it. But not that there is still some issue with output mp3 file. I will ask a new question for that. Below code will give you idea how to pass recordRTC buffer to lamejs. recordRTC has `ondataavailable` event. We can use to pass buffer data to lamejs.

```
var config = {
            recorderType: StereoAudioRecorder,
            mimeType: 'audio/wav',
            timeSlice: 1000, // concatenate intervals based blobs
            ondataavailable: function(e) {
                    mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(2, 44100, 128); 
                    log(' data available')
                    const leftsamples = new Int16Array(e.data);   //for stereo
                    const rightsamples = new Int16Array(e.data);  //for stereo
                    let mp3Tmp = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(leftsamples, rightsamples);
                    let fmp3Tmp = mp3encoder.flush();
                    let mp3Ct= fmp3Tmp.length;
                    if(mp3Ct>0) {
                        mp3Data.push(fmp3Tmp);
                    }
            }
        }
        mediaRecorder = RecordRTC(webcamStream,config);



mediaRecorder.stopRecording(function() {
            let fmp3Tmp = mp3encoder.flush();
            if (fmp3Tmp.length > 0) {
                mp3Data.push(new Int8Array(fmp3Tmp));
            }
           blob = new Blob(mp3Data, {type: 'audio/mp3'});
           invokeSaveAsDialog(blob); //download file
        });
```

Comment: Please could you add a link to the related question about the MP3 files produce. Thanks.

Comment: @TimHunt, I didn't implement recording functionality as I faced many issues including weird behavior of sound when trying to convert the audio to MP3. I gave up on that and left the feature out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Newbie. I recently found https://github.com/elsmr/mp3-mediarecorder which might be the answer to my problem, but I have not yet had time to try it.

Comment: That seems good. I didn't find it back when I was struggling so I cannot comment on it. Give it a try. Different browsers with varying ways they work make lives of developers hell :). I wish there was one standard. I wish you best of luck.

Comment: @TimHunt The library you mentioned is useful if user want to convert audio to mp3 on recording end, it will not help in converting buffer, because `ondataavailable` only be available at the end of recording